# How to smoothly fade 2 textures without alpha in GLSL?

Tags: three.js, mapping, glsl, shader, textures

I'm doing a shader to apply dynamic textures on a terrain chunk generated with ThreeJS.
The tilemap is used to define where each textures is supposed to take place.

E.g.
The tile used:

[image: img]

Here's the actual render :

[image: Actual render of the shader]

Now I need to blend them together to get smooth transitions between each textures.
This is the render I want to achieve :

[image: Expected result]

Any idea how to achieve this **without alpha channels** ?

My vertex shader :

```
uniform sampler2D heightCH1;
uniform sampler2D heightCH2;
uniform sampler2D tile;
uniform float bumpScale;

varying float vAmount;
varying float vColor;
varying vec2 vUV;

void main() 
{
    vUV = uv;
    vec4 bumpData = texture2D(heightCH2, uv);
    vec4 tileData = texture2D(tile, uv);

    vAmount = bumpData.r;
    vColor = tileData.r;

    vec3 newPosition = position + normal * bumpScale * vAmount;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(newPosition, 1.0);
}
```

And my fragment shader :

```
uniform sampler2D tile;
uniform sampler2D heightCH1;
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;
uniform sampler2D texture3;
uniform sampler2D texture4;
uniform sampler2D texture5;
uniform sampler2D texture6;
uniform sampler2D texture7;
uniform sampler2D texture8;
uniform sampler2D texture9;
uniform sampler2D texture10;
uniform sampler2D texture11;
uniform sampler2D texture12;
uniform sampler2D texture13;
uniform sampler2D texture14;
uniform sampler2D texture15;
uniform float mapping[15];

varying vec2 vUV;
out vec4 FragColor;

int getNearestColorIndex(float tileColor)
{
    int nearestIndex = 0;
    float diff = abs(tileColor - mapping[nearestIndex]);
    for (int i = 1; i < mapping.length(); i++)
    {
        float tempDiff = abs(tileColor - mapping[i]);
        if (tempDiff <= diff)
        {
            diff = tempDiff;
            nearestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return nearestIndex;
}

vec4 getTexelForColorIndex(int index)
{
    vec4 t0;

    if (index == 0) t0 = texture2D(texture1, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 1) t0 = texture2D(texture2, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 2) t0 = texture2D(texture3, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 3) t0 = texture2D(texture4, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 4) t0 = texture2D(texture5, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 5) t0 = texture2D(texture6, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 6) t0 = texture2D(texture7, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 7) t0 = texture2D(texture8, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 8) t0 = texture2D(texture9, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 9) t0 = texture2D(texture10, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 10) t0 = texture2D(texture11, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 11) t0 = texture2D(texture12, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 12) t0 = texture2D(texture13, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 13) t0 = texture2D(texture14, vUV * 40.0);
    else if (index == 14) t0 = texture2D(texture15, vUV * 40.0);

    return t0;
}

void main() 
{
    vec4 tileColors = texture2D(tile, vUV);
    int nearestIndex = getNearestColorIndex(tileColors.r);
    vec4 colorToApply = getTexelForColorIndex(nearestIndex);
    
    FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) + colorToApply;
}
```

Thank you by advance for your help

Comment: You can try to use [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml), which performs linear interpolation between textures. You can sample both textures at the same position, then mix them together.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point is that textures doesn't overlap.
As I described before, each pixel is defined in the `tile` sampler2D.
Maybe I don't understand your idea...

Comment: To blur the image you've already created you could implement a gaussian blur. The idea is to average neighboring pixels. There are tons of examples on this. You might also want to use floor() instead of getNearestColorIndex().

Comment: getNearestColorIndex() returns the nearest color of the tile which defines what texture should be displayed.The proposition of @42yeah is good ; I have the two textures I want to blend but `mix` function need a third argument that I don't know how to compute.
Any idea ?

Comment: @Sufhal sorry for the late reply. If your image contains an alpha channel, the third argument can be just that. Otherwise, you can create a mask texture, and use the sample it as the third argument.

Comment: It’s exactly something I can’t do. The chunk tile map (textures placement definition) is only 256x256. If I use alpha channel, the blending will not be smooth. Only thing I can do is getting textures around for getting this third argument